# write a file to a folder in the android device internal storage

Tags: android, directory, android-internal-storage

I have a folder, called MyFolder, in the android device internal storage root directory. There is no external sd card mounted. The folder can be checked using says, ES file manager
 I want to write a file to that directory.
 I try the followings but seem all are not what I want. So how should sd be?
 Please help.

```
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //      File sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)  ;
    //      File sd = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    //      File sd = Environment.getRootDirectory()  ; // system
    //      File sd = Environment.getDataDirectory()  ; 


    backupDBPath = "MyFolder/_subfolder/mydata.txt";

    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
```

Comment: is this an easy or difficult question?

Comment: I check again the path of it on ES file manager and it is "mnt\sdcard\Myfolder" and the file is written there. I should have tested and debugged it more carefully.

Comment: You asked how to store a file on internal storage, not external storage

Comment: This is how I see it. I connect the android device via the Windows 10 desktop. Find the device on the window folder. Click on an icon labelled "internal storage" and it shows all the folders include \MyFolder. The path shown by ES file manager on the android device is , unexpectedly, "mnt\sdcard\Myfolder"

Answer (score 7):

If your directory located in the internal data directory of your app, you could write the code.

```
File directory = new File(this.getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyFolder");

        if(!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdir();

        File newFile = new File(directory, "myText.txt");

        if(!newFile.exists()){
            try {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try  {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            outputWriter.write("Test Document");
            outputWriter.close();

            //display file saved message
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

From the official document: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

The device has removable(SD Card) or non-removable storage(Internal shared storage). Both are called external storage. Suppose you could create the directory in "Internal Shared storage", you could write the code below.

```
File directory = new File(Enviroment.getExternalStorage+File.separator+"MyFolder");//new File(this.getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyFolder");
```

Note: If you have to use getExternalStorage, you should give the storage permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score -1):

From an app, you cannot write a file anywhere you'd like on the device's internal storage, it has to be located in the app's internal directory or app cache directory.

> When saving a file to internal storage, you can acquire the
> appropriate directory as a File by calling one of two methods:
>
> getFilesDir() Returns a File representing an internal directory for
> your app.
>
> getCacheDir() Returns a File representing an internal
> directory for your app's temporary cache files.

You could write:

```
String backupDBPath = "/_subfolder/";
String fileName = "mydata.txt";
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + backupDBPath, filename);
```

More infos here:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html