# Android: How to write file to directory

Tags: android, file

I think this has to be a setup problem, but I can't figure it out.  All I want to do is to write to a file on my android phone sdcard and the be able to get the file from my phone at the end of the day.

I am trying to write to a directory I have created from the file explorer.  I created the directory FFT, and from the file explorer I have copied a file to it.  When I look at the directory using ES File Explorer I can see the directory and the file in storage/emulated/0/FFT/Constants.java.  I know the directory can be written to, just not from my android application.

I have tried so many things, I'm not sure what is real anymore.

In my AndroidManifold.xml I have a line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My attempted code to figure it out:

```
boolean  foo = isExternalStorageWritable();
if (! foo){
    textView.setText("xNot Writeable");
}
else {
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    fullPath += "/FFT";
    File dir = new File(fullPath);

    // Make sure the directory exists
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();

    long len = dir.length();

    String filePath = fullPath + "/index.html";
    File file = new File(filePath);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            fos.write(23); //"Anyone Listening: ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (! file.canWrite()){
        textView.setText("zNot Writeable" + Long.toString(len));
    }
    else {
    }
```

With, copied from somewhere

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Foo is true, the device seems writeable
the directory exists and mkDir is not called
len is 4096
fos = null
file.canWrite is false.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316348/9060917

Comment: Did you ask the runtime permission for storage?

Comment: Like this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Praveen I took your example and changes the path to:          String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        fullPath += File.separator + "FFT"; and get the same result.  at newFile.createNewFile I get IOException "No such file or directory"